# C++ class member function alias template preventing brace-enclosed initializer list from becoming identified as pair/tuple

Tags: c++

I'm working on a C++ template for competitive programming to shorten the amount of code I need to type when solving problems. One part of the syntax that I wish to shorten is the member function names of specific STL classes, such as the `.push_back(item)` member function of a vector to something like `.pb(item)`. The code I currently use is the following:

```cpp
// (I believe) this code allows me to dynamically generate all overloads without having to explicitly name the types
#define alias(type, from, to) template<typename... Ts> decltype(type<T...>().from(std::declval<Ts>()...)) to(Ts...s) {return this->from(s...);}

template <typename ...T>
struct _vector : public vector<T...> {
  alias(vector, push_back, pb);
};
```

This code has worked for basic functionality so far, such as `v.pb(1)` where `v` is a vector of integers. However, the following code doesn't seem to work:

```cpp
int main() {
  _vector<pair<int, int>> v;
  v.pb({1, 2}); // this generates an error
  v.push_back({1, 2}); // this works fine
}
```

The error message the compiler throws is:

```
error: no matching function for call to '_vector<std::pair<int, int> >::pb(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
```

It seems as if the alias prevents the pair/tuple syntax of the elements surrounded by curly braces from being identified and automatically casted into the appropriate pair/tuple type.

Could anybody let me know why this happens, and if possible, present a solution to this issue? Thanks!

Comment: You are not allowed to use identifiers in global namespace started with underscore.

Comment: You can use `emplace_back(1, 2);`. For push_back to work you need to make the forwarding function take specifically a `std::pair<int, int>`.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that `emplace_back` existed...completely forgot about it. As constructor inheritance for classes is a lot easier (`#define inh_cons(name) using name<T...>::name;`), I think I'll stick to using `.eb(args)` for `.emplace_back(args)` for now.

Answer (score 0):

`{1, 2}` has no type and cannot be deduced for `Ts...` (can be currently for `initializer_list<T>`).

You might do: `v.pb(pair{1, 2})` (thanks to CTAD in C++17)

One way to shorten thing is:

```
#define pb push_back
```

and then

```
std::vector <int> v;

v.pb (42); // Extra space
```

or

```
#define pb(...) push_back(__VA_ARGS__)
```

and then

```
std::vector <int> v;

v.pb(42);
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. As for the macro idea, I'm trying to limit my usage to prevent collisions with variables. Maybe push_back isn't the best example, but for something like `.s()` for size where `s` can also be a commonly used variable name, macros tend to pollute the namespace.

Comment: `#define pb push_back` are you serious?

Comment: I've seen other people who do competitive programming include that in their templates. It's not as uncommon as you would believe...